# Increase the size of the text box in the BigQuery UI

Tags: user-interface, google-bigquery

This is a silly question. I write lots of queries, sometimes long, in the BigQuery UI. The text box only displays a dozen lines or so, which forces me to scroll a lot, all the time. Is there a way to increase the size of the text box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes sure, there is a divider you can use to make bigger, if you don't see check your browser extensions as it might cut it out.

[image]

Comment: Also note the use of BQ Mate - a phenomenal Chrome extension for those using BQ a lot